# How to retrieve linked work items from list of commits

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to retrieve list of linked work items using list of commit ids.

Found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#commits-by-a-list-of-commit-ids) Commit Azure DevOps REST API, which does not return linked workitems due to below note on ids parameter.

*May not be combined with other parameters.*

Is there any other API to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

> How to retrieve linked work items from list of commits

We could use the `includeWorkItems` in the request body with the REST API [Commits - Get Commits Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples) to get the linked workitems:

```
{
  "includeWorkItems": "true"
}
```

But when there is no workitem associated in the commit, the return value is `"workItems": []`, we need to filter out such results.

Please check my powershell scripts:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName>/<YourProjectName>/_apis/git/repositories/<RepositoriesId>/commitsbatch?api-version=6.0"

$connectionToken="Your PAT Here"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
$body=@"
  {

    "includeWorkItems": "true"

  }
"@
Write-Host "$url"
$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method POST 

$CommitIDsInfo = $response.value | Where-Object{$_.workitems -ne ""} | select commitid, workitems


$WorkItems = $CommitIDsInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

Write-Host $WorkItems
```

The test result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Leo I am using .NET API, so I am happy with REST API sample. Which example did you end up using on GET Commits Batch API? Commits between two versions or Commits by a list of commit IDs? Consuming Commits Batch API by Commits by a list of commit IDs with includeWorkItems parameter set does not return work items but the former one does. Ps. This ADO instance is for enterprise client.  Happy to report this issue via other MS suggested channel as well

Comment: @Mlh, None of them, just give a simple test sample with Request body ` "includeWorkItems": "true"`. Which sample you want to use?

Comment: On Get Commits Batch  setting "ids" does not return workitems. Also Commits - Get (get single commit by ID) does not return included workitems.

Comment: @Mlh, Unfortunately, this option does not exist in the Get (one/multi) Commit API, if we specify the commit ID(s), we could not get the related workitems, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Sorry Leo it did not, as mentioned on comments would like to get workitems when consumed this API with ids parameter set

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looping through each of the commit hash values. In the request use the same commit hash for "fromCommitid" and "toCommitid" values. Something like:

```
{
  "includeWorkItems": "true",
  "fromCommitId": "ca199fd56",
  "toCommitId": "ca199fd56"
}
```